# Database - Should I define a max length for stored url?

Tags: database, url, storage, spam-prevention, maxlength

I'm building a small webapplication which should store urls as input of a form. Sometimes urls can have attributes, parameters etc. like *https:/www.stackoverflow.com/search?q=This+could+be+a+very+long+string*. But some 'experts' could make use out of the missing validator, which checks the length of the string. Otherwise a limitation would may let occur an error if the url is to long.

I'm using for now SQLite3, but the solution should work database-independent.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are worried about. You can limit the size of the string in the browser, web app and database but that might not be the real problem.

Comment: If I limit the url-length server-side (inside the script, database) some string may could not be stored, because they are too long. Without any users could over the time insert correct urls with tenthousands of characters or even more, which would only bloats the database. See it like some sort of spam-prevention.

Comment: A URL is unlimited in length in the RFC spec but some browsers will not accept over 2000 characters so you can limit it using 2000 characters. SPAM is a different issue, which you would solve using business logic such as checking for the existence of the same domain in the database before adding another one (or flagging it to you so you can check).

Comment: Spam is maybe not the right tern, but you got the point. Checking the existence of a link before adding him to the database should be usual method ;)

I just needed a realistic limitation. Thank you.